# Redirecting url with get variables using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the this link: http://www.example.com/articles.php?article_title=this-is-an-article

to

http://www.example.com/articles/this-is-an-article

This is what I have so far in my .htaccess file that doesn't seem to work: 
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z\-]+)$ articles.php?article_title=$1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+articles\.php\?article_title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /articles/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z-]+)/?$ articles.php?article_title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: You need to provide details what is not working? Are there other rules also?

Comment: When trying to access the rewritten url I get a 404 error specifying that the articles.php file wasn't found. No, just the ones I mentioned.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Sorry, the rules were fine (yours and mine) they worked when I changed the browser, I think it's some sort of caching or something, but I still have one issue left which is the ability to access the old link, that will cause the problem of duplicate content.

Comment: What are those old links that you want to redirect to new ones using 301?

Comment: The same links, I want the old "articles.php?article_title=this-is-an-article" to not be accessible.